# Perl XPath statement with a conditional - is that possible?

Tags: perl, xpath

This question has been rephrased.  I am using CPAN Perl modules [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.71/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Eback%28%29) to navigate a website, [HTML::TreeBuilder-XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm#findvalues_%28%24path%29) to capture the content and [xacobeo](https://metacpan.org/module/Xacobeo) to test my XPath code on the HTML/XML.  The goal is to call this Perl script from a PHP-based website and upload the scraped contents into a database.  Therefore, if content is "missing" it still needs to be accounted for.

Below is a tested, reduced sample code depicting my challenge. Note:

1. This page is dynamically filled and contains various `ITEMS` outputted for different stores; a different number of `Products*` will exist for each store.  And those product listings may or may not have an itemized table underneath of it.
2. The captured data has to be in arrays and the association of any itemized list (if it exists) to the Product listing has to be maintained.

Below, the example xml changes per store (as described above) but for brevity I only show one "type" of output.  I realize that all data can be captured into one array and then regex used to decipher the content for the purpose of uploading it into a database.  I am seeking a better knowledge of XPath to help streamline this (and future) solution(s).

```
<!DOCTYPE XHTML>
<table id="8jd9c_ITEMS">
<tr><th style="color:red">The Products we have in stock!</th></tr>

<tr><td><span id="Product_NUTS">We have nuts!</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <!--Table may or may not exist  -->
           <table>                                  
      <tr><td style="color:blue;text-indent:10px">Almonds</td></tr>
      <tr><td style="color:blue;text-indent:10px">Cashews</td></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </table>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><span id="Product_VEGGIES">We have veggies!</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <!--Table may or may not exist -->
    <table>
      <tr><td style="color:blue;text-indent:10px">Carrots</td></tr>
      <tr><td style="color:blue;text-indent:10px">Celery</td></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </table>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><span id="Product_ALCOHOL">We have booze!</span></td></tr>
    <!--In this case, the table does not exist -->
</table>
```

An XPath statement of:

```
'//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/td/span/text()'
```

would find:

```
We have nuts!
we have veggies!
We have booze!
```

And an XPath statement of:

```
'//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/td/table/tr/td/text()'
```

would find:

```
Almonds
Cashews
Carrots
Celery
```

The two XPath statements can be combined:

```
'//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/td/span/text() | //table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/table/tr/td/text()'
```

To find:

```
We have nuts!
Almonds
Cashews
We have veggies!
Carrots
Celery
We have booze!
```

Again, the above array can be deciphered (in the real code) for it's product-to-list association using regex.  **But can the array be built using XPath in a manner that would keep that association?**

For example (pseudo-speak, this does not work):

```
'//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position()>1]/td/span/text() | 
if exists('//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/table)) 
then ("NoTable") else ("TableRef") | 
Save this result into @TableRef ('//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/table/tr/td/text()')'
```

It is not possible to build multi-dimensional arrays (in the traditional sense) in Perl, see [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perlref.html)  But hopefully a solution similar to the above could create something like:

```
@ITEMS[0] => We have nuts!
@ITEMS[1] => nutsREF     <-- say, the last word of the span value + REF
@ITEMS[2] => We have veggies!
@ITEMS[3] => veggiesREF  <-- say, the last word of the span value + REF
@ITEMS[4] => We have booze!
@ITEMS[5] => NoTable     <-- value accounts for the missing info

@nutsREF[0] => Almonds
@nutsREF[1] => Cashews

@veggiesREF[0] => Carrots
@veggiesREF[1] => Celery
```

In the real code the Products are known, so `my @veggiesREF` and `my @nutsREF` can be defined in anticipation of the XPath output.

I realize the XPath if/else/then functionality is in the XPath 2.0 version.  I am on a ubuntu system and working locally, but I am still not clear on whether my apache2 server is using it or the 1.0 version.  How do I check that?

Finally, if you can show how to call a Perl scrip from a PHP form submit AND how to pass back a Perl array to the calling PHP function then that would go along way to getting the bounty.  :)

Thanks!

**FINAL EDIT:**

Comments immediately below this post were directed at an initial post that was too vague.  The subsequent re-post (and bounty) was responded to by ikegami with a very creative use which solved the pseudo problem, but was proving difficult for me to grasp and reuse in my real application - which entails multiple uses on various html pages.  In about the 18th comment in our dialog I finally discovered his meaning and use of ($cat) - an undocumented Perl syntax that he used.  For new readers, understanding that syntax makes it possible to understand (and reformat) his intelligent solution to the problem.  His post certainly meets the basic requirements sought in the OP but does not use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath to do it.

jpalecek uses the HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath but does not place the captured data into arrays for passing back to a PHP function and uploading into a database.

I have learned from both responders and hope this post helps others who are new to Perl, like myself.  Any final contributions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No response. :(  Is my question too wordy?  Some people prefer the extra info.  Is this really an usual request?

Comment: `td[3 and 4 and 6]` does not return the third, fourth and sixth member. The expression in brackets returns true, so all `td`'s are returned. Use `td[position()=3 or position()=4 or position()=6]`.

Comment: You forgot to provide the source XML document (as small as possible, please). It is almost meaningless to ask for an XPath expression that selects certain nodes, if the source XML isn't presented -- this explains well the response (lack of) you are getting.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm not really looking for an exact syntactical answer and posting multiple documents and all their code would be too much to go through - the post is already too long.  It's an architectural question: Choroba solved the obvious syntax mistake.  Question 1 is more complex, but from what I've read XPath does not provide a logical if/else approach to nodes.  Though XPath can provide an "if" selection in a properly formatted predicate, it is more likely my solution is in the Perl code that runs the expression - perhaps working off a returned predicate value(?)

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the brief Question 1 answer.  RE: Question 2, have you ever needed to check for the existence (if/else) of a node _in XPATH_ and change your code accordingly?  I'm leaning towards checking the existence with an XPath expression and then changing the Perl code which is running it.

Comment: @Ricalsin: I usually use XML::XSH2 for XML manipulation which enables you to mix code and XPath in a way. To check the existence of nodes, you can use XPath's `count`.

Comment: @Ricalsin: XPath 2.0 *does* provide an `if` expression. In XPath 1.0 there is no `if` expression but in some cases a single XPath expression may be sufficient to implement conditional choice. This is why it is important to know what the exact case is.

Comment: @choroba Please give a high-level answer (and get the green check mark!  :) ).  I'm curious to know more about your use of XSH2 and approach.  A link to your favorite doc on the subject would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the helpful responses!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev  Thanks for the 1.0 / 2.0 info.  I understand your request.  I would like to let choroba post his response and then link the thread to continue the discussion with more detail.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were to guess, your question is: "How do I get the following from the provided input?"

```
my $categorized_items = {
   'We have nuts!'    => [ 'Almonds', 'Cashwes' ],
   'We have veggies!' => [ 'Carrots', 'Celery' ],
   'We have booze!'   => [ ],
};
```

If so, here's how I'd do it:

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
use XML::LibXML  qw( );

my $root = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO=>\*DATA)->documentElement;

my %cat_items;
for my $cat_tr ($root->findnodes('//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[td/span]')) {
   my ($cat) = map $_->textContent(),
      $cat_tr->findnodes('td/span');

   my @items = map $_->textContent(),
      $cat_tr->findnodes('following-sibling::tr[position()=1]/td/table/tr/td');

   $cat_items{$cat} = \@items;
}

print(Dumper(\%cat_items));

__DATA__
...xml...
```

PS - What you have there isn't valid HTML.

1. A TABLE element cannot be placed directly inside a TR element. There's a missing TD element.
2. A TR element cannot be empty. It must have at least one TH or TD element.

Comment: Hello @ikegami I have added the missing td you mentioned, can you please update your response?  Also, I have a difficult time running your code.  I tried wrapping my xml with `my $xml = <<'__XML__; code here __XML__;` Then `my $parser = XML::LibXML-new() or die "can't ...";` Then `my $root = $parser->parse_string( $xml );` Doesn't work, but I assume it's me missing something simple.

Comment: @Ricalsin, The parser returns a Document. You need to call its (unfortunately named) `documentElement` method to get the root node. I updated my node for the changes in your data, and I added the test code.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami I got it working.  To me, this is advanced code.  I'm studying it.  :)  The `map $_->textContent()` and `my ($cat) = map` segments have me puzzled.  Can you give me what sections of the perldocs I can read to educate myself?  (It seems you're the only one willing to play for 50 points, but I am aware your time and knowledge is worth much more - so "thanks" again.)

Comment: `my ($x) = LISTEXPR;` assigns the first value returned by LISTEXPR to `$x`. [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) transforms a list. Here, it calls `textContent` on every node, and return every string `textContent` returns.

Comment: Hello @ikegami `Map` I have read and understand.  `LISTEXPR` or a man page on `($variable)` I cannot find. Your description makes it sound like some kind of inverted list - where can I read about it?  BTW, the `XML::LibXML` has no function listed as `documentElement`  Am I missing a Perl core manual page discussion on these things, or is working with Perl Modules on CPAN always this difficult/deceptive? (Thanks for your responses.)

Comment: `documentElement` is a method of XML::LibXML::Document

Comment: Can you please explain, @ikegami how your use of ($cat) enables this code to work?  There seems to be no manual pages on this type of syntax.  The best I can determine is that you're using some modified use of **[THIS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic:-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression)** - which, if so, is marked as being "experimental" by the perldoc.  If not, can you please advise where I can look to learn more?

Comment: @Ricalsin, `($cat) = ...;` causes the first value returned by "..." to `$cat`. The assignment operator is documented in perlop.

Comment: @Ricalsin, I actually used `my ($cat)`, which is the same as `(my $cat)`. Since `my $cat` returns `$cat`, `my ($cat) = ...;` is short for `my $cat; ($cat) = ...;`.

Comment: @Ricalsin, Haven't you ever written a sub before? `sub foo { my ($cat) = @_; ... }`

Comment: New to Perl, @ikegami  I just read the perlop and still don't see a description of an assignment operator used as a LISTEXPR which `causes the first value returned by "...;" to $cat` and subsequent values to be scalars within an array so named.  It's great, and I appreciate it.  I'm not fighting you.  I see the results of your code so I know it works.  I'm just trying to learn from what you are writing me and not just copy/paste your code.  (Again, "Thanks.")

Comment: Re "I just read the perlop and still don't see a description of an assignment operator used as a LISTEXPR", that's because it doesn't, nor did I mention anything of the kind. Oddly, perlop doesn't seem to mention you can assign a list to something list-ish. perldata, under "List value constructors", does.

Comment: See also: [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Comment: Hello @ikegami : As someone coming from PHP (and C in embedded systems designs), can you explain to me why Perl has such a complicated means for handling it's variables?  For example, why the flattening of all variables passed in and out of subroutines (which forces things to be passed by reference)?  This is what was hanging me up yesterday.  Is it due to Perl's historical use as a text manipulation language?  I would hate to think it's because the Perl language was poorly conceived.  Can you shed some light, or give a link?

Comment: 1) Nothing forces Perl to pass by reference. It could just as easily have passed everything by value. Having the option to pass by reference is much more useful. 2) Subroutine calls do not flatten anything. 3) Given that everything you said is wrong, it's no wonder you think it's poorly conceived.

Comment: Look, if you have questions, post them as questions. This is very very off topic.

Comment: Why do you say I think everything is ill conceived?  I am asking for your help in understanding Perl and I'm using this post to do that.  I can't be the only one with these questions.  BTW, the docs clearly state that - when passing aggregates - it flattens them.  Never mind, I don't want to upset you.  Thanks for the help you gave.

Comment: BTW "I would hate to think that ..." can also be said as "It can't be that..."  Certainly, I don't suppose to know better than the countless efforts of many people over decades of existence.  I was trying to give you an understanding of where I was intellectually coming from and where my ability to grasp Perl was getting stuck - hence the request for some "light" or a link.  I think you are a great programmer (as seen by your response to my post).  Unfortunately, people who are not so adept (like me) need guys like you to be patient in order to learn.  Again, thanks for the help @ikegami

Comment: Re "the docs clearly state that - when passing aggregates - it flattens them", Evaluating an array in list context returns in contents. That has nothing to do with sub calls.

Comment: Re: "I am asking for your help in understanding Perl and I'm using this post to do that", Yes, and I told you that's not the appropriate place to ask question about Perl's design. I don't mind answering the question. Just post them as questions, not comments. It's not a question of being offended; it's simply hard to ask the question properly and hard to answer it properly.

Comment: "it's simply hard to ask the question properly and hard to answer it properly" - which embodies the struggle of understanding and knowledge.  Sending me to a forum that is "more appropriate" will not help other readers who will invariably be struggling with the same questions.

Comment: Wrong. More people will see your StackOverflow questions than your StackOverflow comments.

Comment: Stated by @ikegami yesterday: "Ricalsin, I actually used my ($cat), which is the same as (my $cat). Since my $cat returns $cat, my ($cat) = ...; is short for my $cat; ($cat) = ...;"  Is there a reason for your personal help being so obfuscated? Is the goal merely to post a link to one of your other posts on PerlMonks and try to score a few more SO points?  You couldn't just say "it is a list (numbered array) because the map function needs it put it's results. You can replicate my syntax with a `my @cat;` and then `@cat[0]` in the `$cat_items{$cat[0]} = \@items;` statement.  Too easy for you?

Comment: And then you followed that with: "@Ricalsin, Haven't you ever written a sub before? sub foo { my ($cat) = @_; ... }" @ikegami you personify the stereotype that programmers suffer: The more proficient they are at code the less capable they are in personal relationships. As I have said, I think you know a lot about computers, code and Perl in particular.  It's a mistake to think that is all there is to success. In the end, architecture and conceptualizing solutions and markets rules the day - not some obfuscated syntax that temporarily promotes your self. Thanks for the learning curve.

Comment: I have to keep my answers short because of where you chose to ask them. I keep telling you, the comments is the wrong place to ask questions, so complaining to me about your choice to ignore that is silly.

Comment: The post is here.  The responses are here - not on some other forum.  I answered the central question I've been asking you in one comment.  Much of our dialog has been me chasing down your need to be mysterious.  I do not wish to be mean to a person who has helped me, but I hope you appreciate my last couple of responses to you.  You're obviously talented, but you are going to keep yourself in the office cubicle writing code and looking for more SO points due to your attitude.  Learn to play on the management side; they've got more money and they need your talent - without the childish games.

Comment: There is not enough space in the comments to post an answer, and that's the only reason the answer was limited. As is, I had to use 5 replies to just scratch the surface of the answer. Yet after being told multiple times that this isn't the appropriate place to ask questions, you're whinning about the quality of the answer. Not only that, but you're launching personal attacks against the one who actually tried to help you. Helping people is the only "game" I play, and you're being a real jerk about it.

Comment: I appreciate the help, @ikegami, I've said that repeatedly.  After discovering the simplistic answer that you could have given early on - and which I posted in ONE comment field (5 comments up) - I offered you some good sound advice.  I have a feeling you will appreciate it more in the future.

Comment: If you are referring to 2012-02-08 08:23:32Z, I couldn't have said that because it makes no sense. There's no such thing as a numbered array. A List is definitely not an array, numbered or otherwise. "the map needs to puts its results" is grammatically wrong and makes no sense. The "replacating syntax" makes no sense, especially when you proceed to give a different syntax. You give absolute no clue as to which syntax you're talking about. And it doesn't answer the question you asked whateover ("What does `($cat) =` do"?). Not that my code does NOT use `($cat) = ` anywhere.

Comment: Finally, the answer is "obfuscated" (dense) because the the limited space available because you asked the question in the wrong place. Again, stop blaming your refusal to play nice on me.

Comment: Okay, relax.  Take a linguistics course in Perl syntax if it makes you happy.  I gave you the bonus several hours ago.  Thanks for the help.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @ikegami Boy! You do have a lot of patience. Hats off!

Answer (score 2):

1. How to ascertain that `something` exists before running `query`. Eg. if `//p[@class='red']` exists, then return `//table`:

   ```
   /.[//p[@class='red']]//table
   ```
2. `x[3 and 4 and 5]`: `3 and 4 and 5` is a boolean expression that yields `true`. Therefore it will get you all `x`s. For 3rd, 4th and 5th you want

   ```
   x[position() >= 3 and position() <= 5]
   ```

Answer for the edited question:

Why don't you use `XML::XPathEngine` with multiple queries?

```
my $xp = XML::XPathEngine->new;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse (something);
```

Then, you can query:

```
my $shops = $xp->findnodes('//table[contains(@id, "ITEMS")]/tr[position() >1]/td[@span]', $tree);
for($shops->get_nodelist) {
  print "Name of shop is ".$xp->findvalue('span/text()', $_)."\n"; # <- query relative to $_
  print "The shop sells:\n". join("\n", $xp->findvalues('parent::*/following-sibling::tr[1][not(span)]/td/table/tr/td', $_));
}
```

This does the same thing as @ikegami's answer (`XML::XPathEngine` is used by `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`). BTW, if the shops can have more lines with products after them, this should be updated.

Comment: Hello @jpalecek Thank you for this answer.  I posted a more descriptive question asking nearly the same thing - and put a bounty of 50 points on it.  Can you take another look?

Comment: Hi @jpalecek I'm trying to run your code.  Using CPAN mods is still difficult for me.  As above with ikegami, the final trick to load it was `my $root = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO=>\*DATA)->documentElement;` The `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` you reference does not even have a parse method description yet `HTML::TreeBuilder` does.  Still, entering `$tree->parse (\*DATA);` does not seem to give me any results.  I apologize for being so utterly clueless.  It seems I lose a lot of time in Perl to things that others seem to know - what am I not reading to help with these apparently simple steps?

Comment: `BTW, if the shops can have more lines with products after them, this should be updated.`  Why do you say this?

Comment: Hi @jpalecek, I discovered that to pass the `__DATA__' contents into the `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` I needed `$tree->parse_file(\*DATA);` And then a slight change to your XPath code to `tr[position() >1]/td[span]` (removing the @) made it work.  Your code uses the HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath module which was in my OP.  It does not put the results into either a hash or array for uploading into a database, which was also in the OP.  I cannot follow ikegami's use of ($cat).  Can you show an elegant way of saving these results?  Also, does your use of $_ save multiple passes over the DOM?